# Return multiple items from spring batch ItemProcessor

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, batch-processing, itemprocessor

I'm writing a spring batch job and in one of my step I have the following code for the processor:

```
@Component
public class SubscriberProcessor implements ItemProcessor<NewsletterSubscriber, Account>, InitializingBean {

    @Autowired
    private AccountService service;

    @Override public Account process(NewsletterSubscriber item) throws Exception {
        if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(item.getId())) {
            return service.getAccount(item.getId());
        }
        // search with email address
        List<Account> accounts = service.findByEmail(item.getEmail());
        checkState(accounts.size() <= 1, "Found more than one account with email %s", item.getEmail());
        return accounts.isEmpty() ? null : accounts.get(0);
    }

    @Override public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        Assert.notNull(service, "account service must be set");
    }
}
```

The above code works but I've found out that there are some edge cases where having more than one `Account` per `NewsletterSubscriber` is allowed. So I need to remove the state check and to pass more than one `Account` to the item writer.

One solution I found is to change both `ItemProcessor` and `ItemWriter` to deal with `List<Account>` type instead of `Account` but this have two drawbacks:

- Code and tests are uglier and harder to write and maintain because of nested lists in writer
- Most important more than one `Account` object may be written in the same transaction because a list given to writer may contain multiple accounts and I'd like to avoid this.

Is there any way, maybe using a listener, or replacing some internal component used by spring batch to avoid lists in processor?

### Update

I've opened [an issue on spring Jira](https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2252) for this problem.

I'm looking into [isComplete](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/core/step/item/FaultTolerantChunkProcessor.java#L160) and [getAdjustedOutputs](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/core/step/item/FaultTolerantChunkProcessor.java#L180) methods in `FaultTolerantChunkProcessor` which are marked as extension points in [`SimpleChunkProcessor`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/core/step/item/SimpleChunkProcessor.java#L233) to see if I can use them in some way to achieve my goal.

Any hint is welcome.

Answer (score 24):

**Item Processor takes one thing in, and returns a list**

```
MyItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<SingleThing,List<ExtractedThingFromSingleThing>> {
    public List<ExtractedThingFromSingleThing> process(SingleThing thing) {
    //parse and convert to list
    }
}
```

**Wrap the downstream writer to iron things out. This way stuff downstream from this writer doesn't have to work with lists.**

```
@StepScope
public class ItemListWriter<T> implements ItemWriter<List<T>> {
    private ItemWriter<T> wrapped;

    public ItemListWriter(ItemWriter<T> wrapped) {
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends List<T>> items) throws Exception {
        for (List<T> subList : items) {
            wrapped.write(subList);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: would we still be able to do this with FlatFileItemWriter ?

Answer (score 5):

There isn't a way to return more than one item per call to an `ItemProcessor` in Spring Batch without getting pretty far into the weeds.  If you really want to know where the relationship between an `ItemProcessor` and `ItemWriter` exits (*not recommended*), take a look at the implementations of the `ChunkProcessor` interface.  While the simple case (`SimpleChunkProcessor`) isn't that bad, if you use any of the fault tolerant logic (skip/retry via `FaultTolerantChunkProcessor`), it get's very unwieldily quick.

A much simpler option would be to move this logic to an `ItemReader` that does this enrichment before returning the item.  Wrap whatever `ItemReader` you're using in a custom `ItemReader` implementation that does the service lookup before returning the item.  In this case, instead of returning a `NewsletterSubscriber` from the reader, you'd be returning an `Account` based on the previous information.

Comment: Your answer is a very good option. However I feel that type conversion belongs to a Processor and while your suggestion works, I will lose the chance to use a [SkipListener](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/SkipListener.html) to get notified of bad input elements since `onSkipInRead` has only info about occurred exception and obviously not about the input element that has caused it.

Comment: I like the suggestion of wrapping the reader. One problem I can see is the reader interface returns a single item so if the OP reads one `NewsletterSubscriber` with the inner read and needs the outer reader to return multiple `Account`s, he can't just return them all. He'll have to manage the backlog and return them one at a time. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @TomSaleeba Yes. Currently working on a CustomReader that extends the ListItemReader since I have a one-to-many input-output relationship. I'm transforming and managing an internal "queue".

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning an Account you return create an AccountWrapper or Collection. The Writer obviously must take this into account :)

Answer (score -2):

You can made transformer to transform your Pojo( Pojo object from file) to  your Entity
By making the following code :

```
public class Intializer {

public static LGInfo initializeEntity() throws Exception {
    Constructor<LGInfo> constr1 = LGInfo.class.getConstructor();
    LGInfo info = constr1.newInstance();
    return info;
}
}
```

And in your item Processor

```
public class LgItemProcessor<LgBulkLine, LGInfo> implements ItemProcessor<LgBulkLine, LGInfo> {

private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(LgItemProcessor.class);

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public LGInfo process(LgBulkLine item) throws Exception {
    log.info(item);
    return (LGInfo) Intializer.initializeEntity();
}

}
```