# Flatfilewriter throwing an exception when used inside ItemWriterMapper

Tags: spring-batch

I am writing a spring batch application where my processor returns List, as long as return type is list,

```
    @Bean(destroyMethod = "")
    @StepScope
public ItemWriterAdapter<List<MyType>> myWriterAdapter()
{
    ItemWriterAdapter<List<MyType>> writer = new ItemWriterAdapter<>();
    writer.setTargetObject(myWriter(null));
    writer.setTargetMethod("write");
    return writer;
}
```

i keep getting this exception:

org.springframework.batch.item.WriterNotOpenException: Writer must be open before it can be written to
at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter.write(FlatFileItemWriter.java:270)

Writer code:

```
    @Bean
@StepScope
public FlatFileItemWriter< MyType> monetateWriter(@Value(STEP_EC_LOCAL_FILE_PATH) String localFilePath)
{

    
    final FlatFileItemWriter<MyType> writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<>();
    writer.setResource(getLocalFile(localFilePath));
    writer.setHeaderCallback(new MyHeaderCallback());
    writer.setAppendAllowed(true);
    
    writer.setLineAggregator(new DelimitedLineAggregator<MyType>() {
        {
            setDelimiter(COMMA_DELIMITER);
            setFieldExtractor(new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<MyType>() {
                {
                    setNames(new String[] {"id", "title"});
                }
            });
        }
    });      
    return writer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `ItemWriterAdapter` just calls `write` on the `FlatFileItemWriter`. I don't see any added value to using it here. The problem is that this adapter is not correctly scoped as an `ItemStream`, so the delegate is used without its `open` method being called properly upfront, hence the error. If you remove this adapter, it should work as expected.

If you are using this adapter for the sake of supporting a `List` type, I would recommend to clearly define what an item is and use a wrapper type to encapsulate a list of items if needed. This allows you to use the `FlatFileItemWriter` with an aggregate type without having to use such adapter.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, Adapter is added as my processor returns a list of items not item, FlatFile write method works on item not list of items, hence adapter is required

Comment: That's incorrect. You have a `FlatFileItemWriter<MyType>` which is for a single item of type `MyType` and a `ItemWriterAdapter<List<MyType>>` which is for a list. Who is going to wrap your items in a `List`? You should not be expecting this to be done automatically by the adapter, that's why I'm saying I see no added value of this adapter.  You either need to encapsulate the output type of your processor in an aggregate like `class Items { private List<MyType> list; }`, or use something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004959/return-multiple-items-from-spring-batch-itemprocessor